# In IntelliJ IDEA, can I re-order watch expressions?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

After doing a quick search, I only found the main documentation that tells me how to add, edit, and remove them, but not how to move them around.  I have tried dragging them around, but that doesn't seem to change anything.

I want to do this so I can see related data together but more efficient debugging.  I just don't necessarily think or see what I need to debug all at once.

P.S. I'm using this with a Ruby on Rails project, with the Ruby plug-in installed, and RVM Ruby-Rails Gemset chosen, and a Rails module added to the project, running a Test Unit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the Up and Down icons at the bottom of the window.  I guess I just wanted the dragging to work =/.

[image: Watches dialog with Up and Down arrows highlighted]